# How to setup project with pybuilder with python 3?

Tags: python, automation

I have downloaded pybuilder and installed python 3.4. How to configure pybuilder

Answer (score 1):

Just google it? There are enough tutorials out there. For example [Pybuilder tutorial](http://pybuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)